# ADF SQL Query with single quotes around dates

Tags: oracle, azure, escaping, concatenation, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to do a simple pull from oracle based on a date. Eventually, I need this query to be dynamic hence using @concat() function in ADF. For simplicity sake I want to run the below oracle query in ADF with concat.

Since oracle requires single quotes I'm trying to escape it by using two single quotes.

oracle query:

```sql
select * from schema.customer where updated > to_date('06/25/2019','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

here's my ADF text:

> @concat('select * from iris.iris_customer where updated >
>   to_date(','''06/25/2019''','''MM/DD/YYYY''',');')

I'm using to_date because I was getting the 'not a valid month' error and thought I could resolve it. Here's the error I'm getting:

> {
>       "errorCode": "2200",
>       "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorUnclassifiedError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Odbc
>   Operation
>   Failed.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Odbc.OdbcConnector,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR
>   [22008] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol
>   driver][Oracle]ORA-01843: not a valid month,Source=msora28.dll,'",
>       "failureType": "UserError",
>       "target": "copy_to_adl" }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `''` for escaping single quote.

My Example: `@{concat('DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE [ColumnDate] LIKE','''',pipeline().parameters.processYear,pipeline().parameters.processMonth,'%','''')}`

Comment: oh i just saw you were using the correct adf syntax. 
Why don't you output in a variable your expression to see the result?

Comment: Ooo - How do I do that?

Comment: you have variables next to parameters, define one, and then take activity SetVariable and in expression section, you just put your @concat('select * from iris.iris_customer where updated > to_date(','''06/25/2019''','''MM/DD/YYYY''',');')
in output of pipeline you should check output of setvariable activity. There you will see what happens with your expression. :)

Comment: This is awesome! THANK YOU!

`code select * from iris.iris_customer where updated > to_date('06/25/2019''MM/DD/YYYY');
`

I'm missing a comma between dates and MM/DD/YYYY. It works!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this SQL Syntax inside Expression builder in ADF Data Flows to escape single quotes:

"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Id = {$myVar} AND Gender = 'M'"